# Android: can I handle onClick of BaseAdapter items in Activity where the ListView is created?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, listview-adapter

I have a custom adapter for `ListView` using custom adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`. In this custom adapter I have a view holder that holds the items shown in every list item.

Can I get a click callback of certain list item child `View` **IN**  the `Activity` where I create and fill my `ListView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your adapter class:

```
private ViewClickListener mViewClickListener;

public interface ViewClickListener {
    void onImageClicked(int position);
}

public void setViewClickListener (ViewClickListener viewClickListener) {
    mViewClickListener = viewClickListener;
}
```

You let your `Activity` implement `ViewClickListener` interface. Remember to call `myAdapter.setViewClickListener(this);` in the `Activity`

In the `getView` method:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mViewClickListener.onImageClicked(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: would this handle a listview item click? OR a view in an item of the listview?

Comment: This is for the whole item, so you need to get action when view inside list item is clicked?

Comment: exactly! for a specific item in a listview item.

Comment: Updated the answer, you can also have constructor for the adapter which takes the ViewClickListener as parameter so you don't have to remember setting it afterwards

Comment: Thank you Niko. Didn't know i was able to do that.